# search filter bar in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery

i have a  with data role 'page' and inside it under 'content' i have multiple 'collapsible' items. each collapsible item will have some description. I need to a search filter ( as it appears for list views). how do i achieve this?

thanks

Comment: Here is the answer to your query
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-can-i-get-the-data-filter-working-on-a-set-of-values-in-a-div-with-data-role-collapsible-set-on-an-option-list

Answer (score 3):

Simply Add  data-filter="true" to your <ul> element. You may get more info at http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html and scroll down to search filter.